# OnEdit function script with google Spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

I'm using Google spreadsheet, 
I would like to set up a script which allows to display in cell B1 the date when cell A1 is modified knowing that cell A1 is modified automatically with the function importrange.

I used the following script without success because it's working only when user modifies manually the cell:

```
function onEdit() {
  var cell = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange();
  var col = cell.getColumn();
  var row = cell.getRow();
  var value = cell.getValue();
  var col2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(row,col+7);
  if (col == 6 && (value=="RED"))
    return col2.setValue(new Date());
}
```

Could you help me?

THANKS

Comment: Won't Work with `onEdit()`. If it's absolutely essential, consider running a timed trigger to poll the value every 5 minutes or so and check against already stored `proprety` using `propertiesService`

Comment: Hello, Could explain with more details?

Comment: @Youness The reasoning is explained in the Apps Script documentation on triggers - didn't you do any research before asking this question? Triggers do not activate for programmatic changes - only explicit user actions.

Comment: I just spent 5H of research, If you have a simple example of javascript regarding my subject , I will be grateful

Comment: Do you have access to the source sheet,from where the importrange is retrieving the data? If so and if the source sheet is user edited,You maybe able to run a installed trigger onEdit() there to change the destination sheet.

Comment: Yes I have access to the source,
The cell of the source sheet is in the form of a calculation formula.
Can onEdit() work with it ?

Comment: No. A human has to edit something. Yes,If the result of the calculation is the result of a real human editing something anywhere in that sheet.